# How to unit test private features of library (TDD) with CMake

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, cmake, tdd

I want to set up my project with CMake such that it can be developed using TDD, which means **including and testing internal headers**. But setting up the library correctly with CMake hides these implementation details (and correctly so for external use) from my unit tests.

Given a file and folder structure like this:

```
Foo
|-- include
|   `-- Foo
|       `-- Foo.h
|-- CmakeLists.txt
|-- src
|   |-- Bar
|   |   |-- Bar.h
|   |   `-- Bar.cpp
|   |-- Baz
|   |   |-- Baz.h
|   |   `-- Baz.cpp
|   |-- Foo.cpp
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt
`-- test
    |-- Bar
    |   `-- BarTest.cpp
    |-- Baz
    |   `-- BazTest.cpp
    |-- FooTest.cpp
    `-- CMakeLists.txt
```

Foo/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(Foo)
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(src)
if(BUILD_TESTING)
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif()
```

Foo/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Foo)
target_include_directories(Foo
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)

target_sources(Foo
    PRIVATE
        Foo.cpp
        Bar/Bar.cpp
        Baz/Baz.cpp
)
```

Foo/test/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
include(Catch)

add_executable(FooTest
    FooTest.cpp
    Bar/BarTest.cpp # This file can't #include "Bar/Bar.h"
    Baz/BazTest.cpp # This file can't #include "Baz/Baz.h"
)

target_link_libraries(FooTest
    PRIVATE
        Foo
        Catch2::Catch2
)
```

The problem now is that FooTest links against Foo in a way that other projects do when they need the Foo library as a dependency. This creates the problem that I can't run unit tests in `Bar/BarTest.cpp` and `Baz/BazTest.cpp` which includes the files `#include "Bar/Bar.h"` and `#include "Baz/Baz.h`.
Ideally in my mind a solution would be able to get an internal `shortcut` target to Foo which includes everything as PUBLIC which then I can run tests on. But when installed the internal headers are private and only files in `include/Foo/` is public.

Solutions I've seen is either to create many sub targets and include just what you need for each test. But this seems cumbersome and fits not very good with package managers such as Conan in a very modular setup.

Other solution is to create a duplicate Foo target where everything is public, but this requires me to write everything twice. Sounds like a dirty way to me.

A final solution I thought about is to create an internal target FooInternal with every headers and sources set to public which then FooTest can link against. And then create the wrapping library as Foo which links against FooInternal as private, but sets the `include/Foo` folder as public headers.
But this requires either Foo to be an interface target, which then will not have any `libFoo` to export, having me to create custom logic to rename or somehow setup CMake to use the `libFooInternal` as the correct lib file. Again this sounds dirty and I'm not sure how this would work in practice.

Are there any obvious solutions I am being oblivious about, or does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Why can't you run unit tests? I don't understand what you mean here, except that you seem to have a design problem.

Comment: I bolded my main problem, it was probably difficult to see in my wall of text.
I want to test internal headers, those that are not placed in the Foo/include/Foo folder.

Comment: So you need to add the `src` folder to your include path as well for the tests? It's TDD, so it's invasive, and you cannot use the "standard" access. You need to add `src`.

Comment: My proposal is that, even with TDD, you should test the public facing interface of your library. If the internals of your internal library is too complex, then move it to another library, which you can test, and whose public interface will be part of the private implementation of the consumer. Big monolithic libraries are bad practice. However its okay to summary a bunch of them in one library as to use 100 very small ones.

Comment: @Superlokkus :
As a general point I agree. Unit tests gets brittle if they care too much about implementation details.
If Foo.cpp includes Bar.h and Baz.h, that is only one abstraction between FooTest.cpp that include Foo.h and actually (indirectly) testing Bar/Baz.cpp. Which is probably fine.
But is the point where it gets to two abstraction layers the point where doing TDD gets hard, is the same point where it should be pulled out to its own standalone lib?

As a second point, for converting old projects, is there any smooth way to test internal headers anyway?

Comment: Note that you could reuse the same headers and sources files for multiple targets in CMake (don't forget to organize your files in CMake Variables) , so I think it's also ok to just create targets for test purposes which reveal the internal source files. Thats also fine for header only projects or when using external/leagacy projects

Comment: As far as I have understood it, going by modern CMake standards such as expressed by Daniel Pfeifer, you should avoid using variables as much as possible, but rather set the files on the target directly. I am changing up the entire build tool stack for a large company, and the less things the developers have to worry about in the CMakeLists files the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit3:
Solution from edit2 will actually not work well with build trees that contains multiple libraries, because it gives targets access to linked targets internal headers.
Solution offered by Brad King on Kitwares CMake gitlab that was finally used is

```
add_library(foo foo.c)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:$<$<BOOL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:FOO_PRIVATE>>:/path/to/foo/private/include>>")
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY FOO_PRIVATE 1)

add_executable(test_foo test_foo.c)
target_link_libraries(test_foo foo)
set_property(TARGET test_foo PROPERTY FOO_PRIVATE 1)
```

source: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19048

---

edit2: The final solution which ended up being ridiculously simple was just to set the include paths to

```
target_include_directories(Foo
    PUBLIC
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}>
)
```

---

edit1: After looking at the video steveire linked shows that I have done too little programming and testing lately and too much devops oriented work.
I need to be able to test internal headers. Back to the original problem on how to test it correctly with CMake with the given setup. Will update this answer when I find a compelling solution.

---

Original: After going by Superlokkus' comment and discussion on the cpplang slack, it seems to be best never to test internal headers.
If the number of abstractions between the tests that use the public headers and the innermost .cpp file is too large, split it into a standalone library.

Comment: 'Don't test internal headers' is not the right conclusion. There are good recommendations here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cVZvoFGJTU