# CMake and library : how to hide some code to clients, but not to unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I'd need some advices about the structure of my CMake project. I created a SOA module, and isolated the SOA part from the business core by isolating the latter in a library. So, the SOA part is a kind of facade. Also, I plan to unit test each part.

The library will have only two clients :

- its unit tests
- the SOA executable

So here is the planned structure :

```
└── MyProject
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── src
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── a.h
    │   ├── a.cpp
    │   └── main.cpp
    ├── test
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── data
    │   │   └── testdata.yyy
    │   └── testcase.cpp
    └── MyProject_Library
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── include
        │   ├── x.h
        │   └── y.h
        ├── src
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── x.cpp
        │   ├── y.cpp
        │   ├── z.h
        │   └── z.cpp
        └── test
            ├── CMakeLists.txt
            ├── data
            │   └── testdata.xxx
            ├── test_x.cpp
            ├── test_y.cpp
            └── test_z.cpp  // cannot access to z.h
```

When calling `target_sources()` for the library, I added z.h as `PRIVATE`, so that it can't be viewed by the library's client. But so, it cannot be seen either by the unit tests... And I'd like to test the z component.

I hid z.h in the library (= I don't put it in the include library)

Here is what I've done for CMake (sorry : it is dirty, because I am learning CMake...), but maybe you could skip this tedious part, and **go directly to the end of the message** :

**MyProject/CMakeLists.txt :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(MyProject)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(MyLib)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

**MyProject/src/CMakeLists.txt :**

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE /ZI /EHa)
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE /INCREMENTAL)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB_PROJECT_NAME}/include)
```

**MyProject/MyProject_Lib/CMakeLists.txt :**

```
set(LIB_PROJECT_NAME "MyProject_Lib" PARENT_SCOPE)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

**MyProject/MyProject_Lib/src/CMakeLists.txt :**

```
add_library(LIB_PROJECT_NAME STATIC)

target_sources(LIB_PROJECT_NAME
               PRIVATE
                   x.cpp
                   y.cpp
                   z.h
                   z.cpp
               PUBLIC
                   x.h
                   y.h
                   z.h)

target_include_directories(LIB_PROJECT_NAME
                           PRIVATE
                           .
                           PUBLIC
                           ../include)
```

**MyProject/MyProject_Lib/test/CMakeLists.txt :**

```
set(TEST_PROJECT_NAME "MyProject_Lib_Test")

add_executable(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME})

set(TEST_DIR_NAME test)

target_sources(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME}
               PUBLIC
                   doctest.h
                   test_z.h
                   test_z.cpp
               PUBLIC
                   ../include/MyProject_Lib/test_z.h)
                   
target_include_directories(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME}
                           PUBLIC
                               ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                               ${LIB_PROJECT_NAME}/include/)

target_compile_definitions(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE WIN32)

set_target_properties(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
                      OUTPUT_NAME ${TEST_PROJECT_NAME})

target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB_PROJECT_NAME})

add_test(NAME "Test of library"
         COMMAND ${TEST_PROJECT_NAME}
         WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

### So the question is :

**How can I hide z.h to the library client, but not to the unit tests of the library ?**

Comment: It seems that this thread could resolve my problem :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652349/how-to-unit-test-private-features-of-library-tdd-with-cmake  I'm going to try the proposed solution.